# Is there any product tour library for use with polymer / web component?

Tags: polymer, polymer-starter-kit

Is there any product tour library for use with polymer / web component? Such as intro.js/Shepherd to guide user on web app build on polymer-start-kit?

Comment: Do you tested Shepherd already? I think it could work. Just use something like this when declaring the steps: `attachTo: this.$.elementId` ... and you should be good to go!

Comment: I tried using the Polymer selector with Shepherd without success. Seems as Shepherd is already using a querySelector under the hood but to get in to the shadow Dom a `.shadowRoot.querySelector()` would be needed.

Comment: Did you find any product tour library? I've found this: https://github.com/aruntk/walk-tour but the last commit was ~2 years ago.

Comment: Eventually, I've settled with https://github.com/xbsoftware/enjoyhint